# Djikstra Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, dijkstra, shortest-path

I have this function to calculate the shortest path using Dijkstra but the code is giving some errors in some test cases.i could bot find out the logical error in the code.Any help will be appreciated.

```
 int minDistance(int *dist, bool *includ,int no_of_vertices);
int* shortestDist(int** graph, int src, int no_of_vertices)
{
     int u,a=no_of_vertices;
     int min = MAXval;int  min_index;
     int* dist= new int[no_of_vertices];     

     bool *includ = new bool[no_of_vertices]; 

     for (int i = 0; i < a ; i++)
       { dist[i] = MAXval;
        includ[i] = false;}


     dist[src] = 0;


     for (int count = 0; count < a-1; count++)
     {


      int u = minDistance(dist, includ,a);

       includ[u] = true;


       for (int v = 0; v < a; v++)


         if (!includ[v] && graph[u][v]  && ((dist[u]+graph[u][v]) < dist[v]))
            dist[v] = dist[u] + graph[u][v];

    }

     return dist;

}
int minDistance(int *dist, bool *includ,int no_of_vertices)
{            


   int min = MAXval;int min_index;

   for (int v = 0; v < no_of_vertices; v++)
   {
     if (includ[v] == false && dist[v] <= min)
         min = dist[v]; min_index = v;
 }
   return min_index;
}
```

Test case:

```
3
2
0 4 0
4 0 1
0 1 0
```

expected o/p

```
0:5
1:1
2:0
```

actual o/p

```
0:1000
1:1
2:0
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "please debug my program" questions are not allowed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am not asking to debug the program.I am just asking to point out any logical error if noticed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `minDistance()`,

```
 if (includ[v] == false && dist[v] <= min)
     min = dist[v]; min_index = v;
```

You missed `{ }`. `min_index = v;` is executed no matter the condition is true or false.

Comment: How'd you psychic this up?  I thought you were being silly, but apparently not as I cannot see code anywhere.